# css with z-index for for button and conflict when scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have tried using css with z-index it doesn't working.By the way, I confuse what query search to find out this issue

```
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
right: -5px;
width: 23px;
height: 22px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 8040;
```

[image]

Comment: can we see the code that you are using ?

Comment: hi, i have edit. try refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index is a CSS property that sets the stack order of specific elements. An element with greater stack order is always in front of another element with lower stack order.

so that, it should be like this. It's depends on element behind your elements

```
.z-index-0{
 index: 0;
}
```